How to preserve existing partition sizes with cloud-init autoinstall in NoCloud configuration
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 with Cloud-Init and an autoinstall configuration to set up the system using NoCloud. Everything works perfectly when I manually define the partition sizes, specifying each in GB and setting the last partition size as -1.
However, in another scenario, I want to keep the existing partition sizes without modifying them. Even when I set preserve: true in the storage: version 2 section, autoinstall still requires me to specify the partition sizes, which leads to errors if left out. A workaround is to manually declare the sizes as shown in fdisk, but this isn’t ideal. Is there a way to configure autoinstall to preserve the partitions without having to re-specify the sizes ?
